# from_unixtime still displaying 19 hours past expected time

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, date-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

I currently have some cleaned data with new columns and formatted correctly, however the clause regarding from_unixtime is stumping me. I have tried the following:

```
from_unixtime(`time@timestamp`, '%H:%i:%s') AS Date_12am,
```

Is the main statement that I'm trying to get to display '00:03:02' where the time is starting at midnight for a 24hr period. I'm in the eastern timezone so I first tried recommended shell commands and verified that my MySQL workbench and config files were also the correct time. I tried setting the above clause to local time, 'SET AS', 'CONVERT', and playing around with the format to see if I could get the right combination. Nothing is seeming to work, so any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
from_unixtime(`time@timestamp`),
data_format_0, data_format_1, data_format_2, data_format_3
FROM my_table_name;

/*The above is for checking to see if data is populated.*/

ALTER TABLE my_table_name
CHANGE data_format_0 OneMinuteAverage DOUBLE,
CHANGE data_format_1 ProductName VARCHAR(250),
CHANGE data_format_2 measruement1 DOUBLE,
CHANGE data_format_3 measurement2 DOUBLE;

SELECT 
from_unixtime(`time@timestamp`, '%Y_%m_%d') AS `Date`,
from_unixtime(`time@timestamp`, '%H:%i:%s') AS Date_12am,
ROUND(OneMinuteAverage, 2) AS OneMinuteAverage, 
ProductName, measurement1, measurement2
FROM my_table_name;
```

[Results from above query displaying unix time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDG8L.png)

Comment: What does `show variables like '%time_zone';` say?

Comment: This sounds like a time zone issue. Is your server on UTC?

Comment: what type is the `time@timestamp` column?  can you show some sample data?

Comment: @ysth the `time@timestamp` column is a REAL32 variable coming from easybuilder pro SQL query. 

@tadman and @Barmar my 'time_zone' value is 'SYSTEM' and my 'SYSTEM_TIME_ZONE' is Eastern Standard Time (my current timezone).

Comment: PS - thank you for catching my mistake in the initial code posting.

Comment: `@ysth` without any `ALTER TABLE` or `CHANGE` the unix that comes out is 1705968054.906. Using `from_unixtime(`time@timestamp`)` get's '2024-01-22 19:00:54.906000' where the `19:00:54` should display `00:00:54`

Answer (score 0):

unix_timestamp returns a localtime for the given epoch seconds, where local means in the timezone of your session/connection, which defaults to your database's default time zone (but some ORMs or clients will set for you based on their environment).  So it is expected that unix_timestamp(1705968054) would return 19:00:54 when in American Eastern Standard Time.  I recommend avoiding unix_timestamp and all other functions that use the session time zone.  Instead you can do:

```
select date_format('1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval 1705968054.906 second, '%H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: This worked, but changed all the times to `00:00:54`. It may have been a little unclear on my end, but I'd like the time to count up over a 24hr period where it starts at `00:00:54` and ends at `23:59:41` for example.

Comment: what counts up?  if it wasn't clear, the 1705968054.906  in my example should be your variable.

Comment: The time counting up starting at midnight. Currently it starts at `19` and counts up every minute (the unix time). I'd like to keep the data, want to efficiently convert the leading `19` to `00` and count up each minute.

Comment: using 1970 + interval and date_format should give you a utc time, not an eastern time, so the 19 should be fixed.  for the rest, I'm still not getting it, it would help if you included a full runnable example in your question (create table, inserts, full select).  show what you are doing well enough that we can try it too